# Best way to pass a get request to Twilio media streams to get the parameters value in Node JS?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

So I have been trying to get values from twilio media streams parameters in my node js app, Would love to know what's a best way to pass a get request to streams.

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. I'm not entirely sure what you're asking here. What is the code you've tried so far and what are the errors you or issues you are having?

Comment: Hey Phil, Thanks but i already solved the issue I was missing .customParameter while trying to get values.